# Clean up pixel noise from raster in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, pixel

I have this raster. It has some pixels near the main objects, this raster is a product of a classification. those little pixels have the same value of other big objects, so I cannot just reclassify. Is there any tool to do this clean up on this raster?.

[image]

Comment: Do some research on "sieving" and see here:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/image-classification/generalizing-classified-output-by-removing-small-isolated-regions.htm

Comment: Have a look at this [tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/majority-filter.htm).